# Return a matching value from 2 dataframes (1 dataframe with single value in cell, 1 with a list in a cell) into 1 dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes:

```
df1
ID           Type     
2456-AA      Coolant      
2457-AA      Elec  

df2
ID                    Task
[2456-AA, 5656-BB]    Check AC
[2456-AA, 2457-AA]    Check Equip.
```

I'm trying return the matched ID's 'Type' from df1 to df2. With the result looking something like this:

```
df2
ID                    Task          Type
[2456-AA, 5656-BB]    Check AC      [Coolant]
[2456-AA, 2457-AA]    Check Equip.  [Coolant , Elec]
```

I tried the following for loop. I udnerstand it isn't the fastest but i'm struggling to workout a faster alternative:

```
def type_identifier(type):
    df = df1.copy()
    device_type = []
    
    for value in df1.ID:
        for x in type:
            if x == value:
                device_type.append(df1.Type.tolist())
            else:
                None
    
    return device_type

df2['test'] = df2['ID'].apply(lambda x: type_identifier(x))
```

Could somebody help me out? and also refer me to material that could help me to better approach problems like these?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) of pandas to convert `df1` to a dictionary, so we can efficiently translate `id` to `type`.

Then, apply lamda that for each `ID` in `df2` converts it to the right type, and assign it to `test` column as you wished.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['2456-AA', '2457-AA'],
'Type':['Coolant', 'Elec']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[['2456-AA', '5656-BB'], ['2456-AA', '2457-AA']],
'Task':['Check AC', 'Check Equip.']})

# Use to dict to convert df1 ids to types
id_to_type = df1.set_index('ID').to_dict()['Type']

# {'2456-AA': 'Coolant', '2457-AA': 'Elec'}
print(id_to_type)

# Apply lamda that for each `ID` in `df2` converts it to the right type
df2['test'] = df2['ID'].apply(lambda x: [id_to_type[t] for t in x if t in id_to_type])

print(df2)
```

Output:

```
                   ID          Task             test
0  [2456-AA, 5656-BB]      Check AC        [Coolant]
1  [2456-AA, 2457-AA]  Check Equip.  [Coolant, Elec]
```

Comment: Hi Aviv! Thank you very much. This was perfect. If I understand correctly It's paramount that I learn lsit comprehensions in order to tackle questions liek this in the future. THank you again!

Comment: Welcome @Ventoii :)